# How to create a background priority SERIAL queue WITH A NAME, in Swift?

Tags: queue, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

Ok, I can greate a global serial background queue like this

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

}
```

but I want my queue to have a name. So I tried this code recommended by Apple (ha!):

```
let queueAttributes = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)
let videoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("videoQueue", queueAttributes);
```

As expected, this fails pointing to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` with this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '__OS_dispatch_queue_attr?'
```

obviously clicking on the error or searching the web gives no clue and autocomplete does not give any clues on what to put there instead.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "name.of.your.queue")
```

or

```
let processingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "your.queue", qos: .background,
                                    attributes: [],
                                    autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit,
                                    target: nil)
```

Noted that `DispatchQueue.Attributes` is a OptionSet, you can pass empty [], or combine several values on it.

Comment: OK, but how do I define this as background QoS?

Comment: Ya, I forgot to tell you answer edited. You’re welcome!